# problema con slider multi item en bootstrap y angular

Tags: bootstrap, angular, slider, carrusel

tengo un carousel multi-item de 3 item por vez, cuando hago click en el boton siguiente o anterior se muestran otros 3 nuevos items y así sucesivamente. el problema que tengo ahorita es que estoy haciendo binding entre el .ts y el .html para poder obtener el valor de la variable Z que modifico cada vez que hago click en el Next o en el Previous ya que esa variable Z la uitlizo como indice de un vector donde tengo alamacenadas las imagenes que muestro en el slider. por eso hago referencia a z , z+1 y z+2 para las 3 primeras imagenes y luego z+3, z+4 y z+5 para las siguientes 3 imagenes cuando se hace click en el boton previous. el gran problema que estoy viendo es que cuando hago click en el boton siguiente, la variable Z se modifica obviamente y todo se me vuelve un desastre xq los valores se mezclan. Como podría mejorar esto? se que ese slider tiene demasido código repetitivo pero intente hacerlo con algunos frameworks ya que con bootstrap no se puede originalmente y no logre hacerlo funcionar. aquí dejo el código que tengo:

```js
<div class="container" id="contenedor-global">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div> <span class="text-hot">
          <b>HOT</b> </span> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div-redondo" class="d-flex ml-2 align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="text-hot align-middle">
              list
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!--<div *ngIf="inmuebles!=null; else espera">-->
  <div class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <h1>{{z}}</h1>
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z].id}}_{{inmuebles[z].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <h1>{{z}}</h1>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2" >Precio: {{inmuebles[i].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2">Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
                </div>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <h1>{{z+1}}</h1>
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+1].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <h1>{{z+1}}</h1>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <h1>{{inmuebles[z+1].fotos[0]}}</h1>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+1].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+2].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <h1>{{z+2}}</h1>
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+2].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+2].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <h1>{{z+2}}</h1>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+2].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+3].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <h1>{{z+3}}</h1>
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+3].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+3].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <h1>{{z+3}}</h1>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+3].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <h1>{{z+4}}</h1>
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+4].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+4].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <h1>{{z+4}}</h1>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+4].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[z+5].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                <h1>{{z+5}}</h1>
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[z+5].id}}_{{inmuebles[z+5].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <h1>{{z+5}}</h1>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+5].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" (click)="anteriorInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" (click)="siguienteInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--</div>
<ng-template #espera>Esperando datos...</ng-template>-->
</div>
```

Aquí es donde incremento los valores de la variable Z, la incremento o decremento de 5 en 5 porque esa es la cantidad de posiciones en la que debo  moverme en el vector de las fotos para poder rotar el carousel.

```js
    anteriorInmueble(){
      (this.z<=0)? this.z=680: this.z=this.z-5;
    }


    siguienteInmueble(){
      (this.z>=680)? this.z=0: this.z=this.z+5;
    }
```